# Django Rest Framework Serializer : get fields of two models

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Hello all been working on Rest API for couple of weeks I have learned about serializers and nested serializer. I am stucked on grabbing fields from Two models is it possible to do in serializer. Here is my code.

```
class Slider(BaseModel):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    section = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        validators=[validators.validate_section_name],
        )

    tag = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        validators=[validators.validate_tag_name],
        )

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Slider'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sliders'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section
```

next model I want to combine in serializer is

```
class SliderImage(BaseModel):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_slider_image_to,
        validators=[],
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    slider = models.ForeignKey(Slider,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='slider_image',
                               )

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Slider Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Slider Images'
```

now is there any way out so that i can get serializers in this way?

expected serializer is as

```
"sliders": [
      {
        "images": [
          "http://34.202.219.142:8000/media/promotion/slider/slider_56cc1829-aa78-40e3-9163-2c7297358de0.png",
          "http://34.202.219.142:8000/media/promotion/slider/slider_4ea6d488-a1f6-4a0a-b522-ae0285e482df.png",
          "http://34.202.219.142:8000/media/promotion/slider/slider_29862eb0-7a2a-4cc4-90b0-3ec5de510d75.png"
        ],
        "section": "bus company",
        "tag": "hot-deals"
      },
```

I tried this in serializers

```
class SliderSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Slider
        fields = '__all__'


class ListSliderSerializer(SliderSerializers):
    class Meta(SliderSerializers.Meta):
        fields = (

            'section',
            'tag',
        )


class GetHomePagePromotionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    sliders = ListSliderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

I am serializing in following way in usecases.py and views.py as

#usecases

```
class GetHomePagePromotionUseCase(BaseUseCase):
    def execute(self):
        self._factory()
        return self._home_page_promotion

    def _factory(self):
        self._home_page_promotion = {
            'sliders': self.list_home_sliders(),
            
        }

    def list_home_sliders(self):
        return SliderImage.objects.all()
```

#views.py

```
class GetHomePagePromotionView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    Use this end-point to get promotion items for the home page
    """
    serializer_class = GetHomePagePromotionSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return GetHomePagePromotionUseCase().execute()
```

I am newbie hope I clarified my question.

Comment: Add your serializer class. Also, add *current* output and *expected* output too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
class ListSliderSerializer(SliderSerializers):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_images(self, instance):
        return [slider_image.image.url for slider_image in instance.slider_image.all()]

    class Meta(SliderSerializers.Meta):
        fields = (
            'images',
            'section',
            'tag',
        )
```

Comment: got attribute error saying this  'SliderImage' object has no attribute 'slider_image'

Comment: how do you serializing the queryset? Can you show your code snippet that used to serialize the data?

Comment: Thanks worked almost but the images are coming not in this pattern http://34.202.219.142:8000/media/promotion/slider/slider_56cc1829-aa78-40e3-9163-2c7297358de0.png instead got upto this ----->>>>media/promotion/slider/slider_56cc1829-aa78-40e3-9163-2c7297358de0.png any improvement ?